# No arbitrage opportunities and interest rate

Tags: risk, arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, self-study

Consider a financial market with one single period, with interest
rate r and one stock S. Suppose that $S_0 =1$ and, for n=1, $S_1$ can take
two different values: 2, 1/2.

For which values of r the market is viable? viable means
(free of arbitrage opportunities).

What if $S_1$ can also take the value 1.

**Author's Solution**

We want to calculate the values of r such that there is an arbitrage
opportunity. We take a portfolio with zero initial value $V_0=0$ Then we
invest the amount q in the stock without risk, we have to invest −q in the risky
stock (q can be negative or positive). We calculate the value of this portfolio in time 2.

$V_1(\omega_1)=q(r-1)$.......(1)

$V_1(\omega_2)=q(r+1/2)$........(2)

So, if r > 1 there is an arbitrage oppportunity taking q positive (money in the
bank account and short position in the risky stock) and if r < −1/2 we have
an arbitrage opportunity with q positive (borrowing money and investing in the
risky stock). The situation does not change if $S_1$ take the value 1.

**My query:**
I want to know,Now if r<-1/2 how there is an arbitrage opportunity?Would any member explain me in his reply?

That means to have a viable market, $r$ must be between **-0.5 To 1**

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one but post separate questions.

Comment: The essence is this: an interest rate of -0.50 means if you put money in the bank you will have half of it a year from now.  It would be better to invest in absolutely anything else which is guaranteed not to lose 50%. And the stock is such an opportunity. Once you have invested all your money in the stock, you may get the idea to **borrow** even money from the bank at -0.50 and invest it in the stock as well. And this is the arbitrage.

Answer (score -2):

$$
\mu = u(\sigma^2)
$$
diffentiating
$$
 diff(u(\sigma^2)^2) = 2u(\sigma^2)u'(\sigma^2)
=2\mu(\sigma^2)u'(\sigma^2)
$$

both answer are right